# Excel OFFSET function with a dynamic row argument

Tags: excel, offset

Sorry about my newbieness here.

So... I have this table:

[image]

And I want to collect some data into a different sheet:

[image]

As example, I am collecting D14, with this formula: =OFFSET(Test_Sheet!$A$18,2,9,1,1).

Problem is:  when I drag the formula to Row 15, the value stays the same because the Argument "rows" it is static. How can I drag down this formula with "rows" argument increasing 1 unit per row? Expected result should be =OFFSET(Test_Sheet!$A$18,**3**,9,1,1).

Thank you all

Comment: You don't need Offset. You could put a direct reference: `=Test_Sheet!D14` and drag that down.

Comment: I did not mention it in my question but I have several small arrays in the same sheet where I need to use this formula. I need to use the OFFSET function (or at least something similar to that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is to create what I call "anchor cells" as references and calculate your offsets from those anchors. In your example, your first anchor is  `Test_Sheet$A18`. For my own convenience, I usually create a named range for that cell.

In my example here, you can see that cell `A4` is named `DataAnchor`.

[image]

Your next anchor is the FIRST cell of your formula ***in relation to the anchor cell***. (Clearly, if you move things around your relative "constants" will change. So be advised.)

In this example, my first cell with the formula is `F8`.

[image]

To get the relative row offset between the anchor row and my formula row, you calculate:

```
ROW()-ROW(DataAnchor)-2
```

That's the *current row number* minus the row number of the anchor minus two.

Then the formula in `F8` copied down becomes

```
=OFFSET(DataAnchor,ROW()-ROW(DataAnchor)-2,2,1,1)
```

Comment: Yes, it is much better but, like you said: "if you move things around your relative "constants" will change".

Any tip to overcome this? I might have several "anchors" in the same worksheet where your functions will be implemented.

Comment: Honestly? More named anchors or "delta" constants (such as the `2` that's in the formula `ROW()-ROW(DataAnchor)-2`) can also be turned into another adjustable named value. You can even calculate those values to automagically adjust as needed. This all depends on your data, your arrangement of the data, etc.